# Jquery $(this).parent().next();

Tags: jquery, html

I will jump to the `<fieldset>` with a class `"secound"`, but the jump doesn't work.
What is wrong in my code?
Sorry for my english and I hope you can help me?

```js
$(".next").click(function(){
    textnext = "next1";
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    if( textnext == $(".next").val()){
        next_fs = $(this).parent(".secound").next();
    }
    next_fs.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<fieldset style="height:100vh">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="next1" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="height:100vh" class="first">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="height:100vh" class="secound">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: you are missing the ) in next_fs.show(); }  you to write  next_fs.show(); })

Comment: This is the code and i will not jump to the next fieldset. i will jump to a custom fieldset with a class. 
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the value of the button you clicked with

```
textnext
```

, you need to do

```
if( textnext == $(this).val()){
    next_fs = $(this).parent(".secound").next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .secound fieldset isn't a parent of the element you are clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

that's what you are trying to do?

```js
$(".next").click(function(){
   
    var textnext = "next1";
  
    var current_fs = $(this).parent();
  
    var next_fs = $(this).parent().nextAll('.secound');
  
   $('body').scrollTop( next_fs.offset().top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
  
<fieldset style="height:50vh">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="next1" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="height:50vh" class="first">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="height:50vh" class="secound"  >
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code and i will not jump to the next fieldset. i will jump to a custom fieldset with a class. 
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar